# Images with size larger than 1 MB give error - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, magento2.3.0, media-images

Is it normal for Magento in version 2.3.0 to fail me when trying to upload an image that is larger than 1 MB?

Comment: check with PHP configuration. It may be due to upload_max_size set to 1MB.

Comment: I have updated this value: upload_max_filesize = 32M, and still does not work, some other idea?

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this issue

1. Create a file in your `pub` directory `phpinfo.php` and add this code in it:
2. Execute this file from your browser `www.yourwebsite.com/phpinfo.php`

If you are getting `404` error, then you magento `.htaccess` is not allowing this file, in that case try to execute this file from shell

```
php pub/phpinfo.php
```

The point of running this file is to get **Loaded Configuration File** location. After this you will get location of `php.ini`

3. Now update `upload_max_size` in `php.ini`
4. Restart apache

It should resolve your issue :)